# How to solve Django 'ModuleNotFoundError' No module named '___main___.models'

Tags: python, django

I would -just- like to import a `module` into my `views.py` file.

I tried different SO solutions like checking for `___init.py___` available in my app and for my app being in `installed_apps` in the `settings`. Everything seems to be set up properly.

Still I get the error. What's happening?

**Here I would like to import the module:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models.py import ratesEUR

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXX&base=EUR")

rates_EUR = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
timestamp = rates_EUR['timestamp']
base = rates_EUR['base']
date = rates_EUR['date']
rates = rates_EUR['rates']
id = 1

rates_new = ratesEUR(id=id, timestamp=timestamp, base=base, date=date, rates=rates)
rates_new.save()


def render_Quotes_app(request, template="Quotes_app/templates/Quotes_app/Quotes_app.html"):
    return render(request, template)
```

**This is the error occuring:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\dashex\Quotes_app\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models.py import ratesEUR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
[Finished in 0.373s]
```

**My settings:**

```
import os.path
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'), )


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Quotes_app',
    'Quotes_appConfig',
    'Wiki_app',
]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Remove `.py` from this line. Do just `from .models import ratesEUR`

Comment: Also `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should have a value! For development make it `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "locahost"]` or just `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`.

Comment: `from models import ratesEUR` worked. The `.` still gave me the error. But thanks for highlighting, solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from models import ratesEUR` worked. Since the files are in the same directory, there is no need for further path declaration.